# how to pass a querystring as a value of a querystring in php

Tags: php

i want to pass a querystring as a value of another querystring in php.]

mycode:

```
$url3="http://hscore3.php?try=1&name=xyz";
$string3="http://ww.php?url=".$url3;
header("location:$string3");
```

In ww.php:

```
echo $_REQUEST['url'];
```

On doing this i am getting output as:

```
"http://hscore3.php?try=1"
```

but i want:

```
"http://hscore3.php?try=1&name=xyz"
```

How to get this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url3="http://hscore3.php?try=1&name=xyz";
$string3="http://ww.php?url=".rawurlencode($url3);
header("location:$string3");
```